# Error using tm package to remove stop-words in R

Tags: r, tm, stop-words

I'm trying to use the tm package to remove stop-words from tokenized text in R, but am getting an "incorrect number of dimensions" error.

Here is an example of the code:
"text" is the name of the tokenized character vector, keywords is the vector that should have the words without stop-words.

```
keywords <- text[!text %in% stopwords(),]
```

Comment: How about removing the comma?

Comment: Yes, the comma was the problem and it works without it. Thanks for catching it